# How to use variable as parameter name in PHP SQLite3 bindparam

Tags: php, sqlite, bindparam

I am using SQLite3 and PHP, and try to write a generic function to execute my queries.

For this I would like to retrieve the name of the parameters from variables in the `bindParam`.

But it doesn't seem to work. Here is a code showing the unexpected behavior:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    $db = new SQLite3(':memory:');
    $db->exec("create table mytable (lsid integer primary key autoincrement, usid TEXT, source TEXT)");

    $myid = 'agoodid';
    $mydatasources = array('home', 'news');
    foreach($mydatasources as $datasource)  {
        $params[] = array(':datasource' => $datasource, ':usid' => $myid);
    }
    echo "here are the inputs : " .PHP_EOL;
    print_r($params);

    $querystring = 'insert into mytable (source, usid) values (:datasource, :usid)' ;
    echo " I prepare the query '$querystring'" . PHP_EOL;
    $query = $db->prepare($querystring);
    foreach($params as $set) {
        foreach($set as $key => $value) {
            echo "  Setting $key = $value." . PHP_EOL;
            $query->bindParam($key, $value, SQLITE3_TEXT);
        }
        echo " I execute the query" . PHP_EOL;
        $queryres[] = $query->execute();
        $query->reset();
    }

    $results = $db->query('select * from mytable');
    echo "and here is what I get : " . PHP_EOL;
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }

?>
```

And here is the final result :

```
Array
(
    [lsid] => 1
    [usid] => agoodid
    [source] => agoodid
)
Array
(
    [lsid] => 2
    [usid] => agoodid
    [source] => agoodid
)
```

All the parameters seem to be bound with the value of the last bound parameter.

The expected result is:

```
Array
(
    [lsid] => 1
    [usid] => agoodid
    [source] => home
)
Array
(
    [lsid] => 2
    [usid] => agoodid
    [source] => news
)
```

How to do this? As a reminder: the aim is to not hard code the name of the parameter in `bindParam`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the `binParam` function wholy wrong. it is attaching to the given parameter in the sql query a reference to the given variable in php.
I have to use `bindValue` instead.